# I have a question about dynamic allocation of memory in c++

Tags: c++

I'm new to c++ and I can't understand something in dynamic allocation.
why does the following program build but gives an error and stops?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    int amount;
    int *p = new int[amount];


    cout << "enter the size of array" << endl;
    cin >> amount;




    for(int i = 0; i < amount ; i++)
    {
        cout << "enter the " << i + 1 << " number" << endl;
        cin >> p[i];
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < amount ; i++)
    {
        cout << "number " << i + 1 << " is : " << p[i] << endl;
    }

    delete []p;


}
```

Comment: `amount` has undefined value. Also note since `c++11` explicit use of `new` is considered a bad practice. Just use `std::vector` in this code and ti will handle memory management for you.

Comment: @MarekR "*since `c++11` explicit use of `new` is considered a bad practice*" - use of `new[]` for arrays was discouraged in favor of `std::vector` long before C++11.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to use `amount` before you have assigned any value to it. You need to read the user's input for `amount` first, THEN allocate using it. Not the other way around.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int amount;

    cout << "enter the size of array" << endl;
    cin >> amount;

    int *p = new int[amount];

    for(int i = 0; i < amount ; i++) {
        cout << "enter the " << i + 1 << " number" << endl;
        cin >> p[i];
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < amount ; i++) {
        cout << "number " << i + 1 << " is : " << p[i] << endl;
    }

    delete[] p;
}
```